# Relationship between the symmetric group representation (Specht module) of a Young diagram and the Young diagram obtained by deleting one row

Tags: co.combinatorics, gr.group-theory, rt.representation-theory, symmetric-groups

Suppose $\lambda$ is a Young diagram, and $\lambda'$ is obtained by deleting one particular row of $\lambda$. Is there any relationship between the symmetric group representation (Specht module) corresponding to $\lambda$ and $\lambda'$?

Another question is: Is there any other relationship between $\lambda$ and $\lambda'$?

Comment: Well, the rank of $\lambda'$ is one more than the rank of $\lambda$.  (Dyson's rank statistic is the first part of the partition minus its number of parts.)

Comment: "Symmetric group representation" is hiding the fact that these two partitions index representations of *different* symmetric groups. (Of course, this does not preclude their being some relation: after all, deleting a single box corresponds to the branching law for the tower of symmetric groups.)

Comment: It's hard to answer your question because the Specht modules are modules for symmetric groups of different degrees. But see for instance 'Row and column removal theorems for homomorphisms between Specht modules' by Fayers and Lyle: https://webspace.maths.qmul.ac.uk/m.fayers/papers/homs.pdf.